# add encrypted dictionary to Microsoft word 2010

Tags: c#, c++

i want add encrypted dictionary to Microsoft word 2010  to used it spell checker of word 2010. i read about MS CSAPI but do not understand how to use it and try to work with word plugin but the performance was very slowly.
please, help me how to do it?

thank's for your time

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your efforts. What problem are you facing?

Comment: i try add plugin in word and loop all words in active word file and check if word spelling of word correct or not but it is very slowly so i want to work with MS CSAPI